# Как сделать определенный порядок вызова методов в html тексте?

Tags: java, android

Я беру с сайта текст, в тексте есть дивы с изображением спойлерами и многим другим, как сделать вызов метода соответствующего вызову. Без разницы как вызывается, метод главное порядок вызова.

Пример:
Текст текст текст изображение текст текст текст сполйер и тд...